# how to ask question to a particular person for example "xxzz" who is as sql server developer

Tags: support

how to ask question to a particular person for example "xxzz" who is as sql server developer. Actually I want to ask a question directly to a person who answered my previous question . Is it possible?

Answer (score 7):

No. Don't try. A person who chooses to participate in this community does not do so to become your personal consultant. See this main meta conversation for more details:

[Ask question from specific person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136423/ask-question-from-specific-person)